# Length of Array of Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I understand that finding the length of a JS object has been answered extensively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

With one of the suggested solutions being `Object.keys(myObj).length`

However, I'm struggling to find out how can I find the length of all **properties** contained on an array of objects.

ie:

```
const users = [
  {
    firstName: "Bruce",
    lastName: "Wayne",
    id: "1",
  },

  {
    firstName: "Peter",
    lastName: "Parker",
    id: "2"
  },

  {
    firstName: "Tony",
    lastName: "Stark",
    id: "3"
  }
];
```

`Object.keys(users).length //3`

Given the example above, How can I output a length of `9` retrieving all the properties on the array of objects?

Could this be done using a `reduce` method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `users.reduce((acc, o) => acc + Object.keys(o).length, 0)`

Comment: Object.keys(users[1]).length

Comment: @DeepikaRao that only gives the length for `[1]` which is `3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `reduce` is the appropriate method - on each iteration, add the number of keys of the current object to the accumulator to sum up the `keys` of every item:

```js
  const users = [
  {
    firstName: "Bruce",
    lastName: "Wayne",
    id: "1",
  },

  {
    firstName: "Peter",
    lastName: "Parker",
    id: "2"
  },

  {
    firstName: "Tony",
    lastName: "Stark",
    id: "3"
  }
];

const totalProps = users.reduce((a, obj) => a + Object.keys(obj).length, 0);
console.log(totalProps);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was lost on how to go about this.